# php how to let the script running on the server even the ajax is completed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to let the script running even the ajax is complete. But what I'm done is the ajax complete after the script processed. The following is my code.

index.php

```
$.ajax({

url:"terminal.php",
dataType:'json',
data: "test=122312&id=dsfsdf",
type: 'post',
success:function(data){

    console.log(data);

},
error:function(data){

    console.log('error');
}
})
```

terminal.php

```
    system("curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/testing/process >/dev/null 2>dev/null &");
    exit;
```

process.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

sleep(10);

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','testing');

$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_hold VALUES('$datetime')";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo "Fail the process";
}   


mysqli_close($con);
```

Please help me if anyone know how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

PHP internally buffers whatever output is being generated and it flushes only at the end of the php script , but you can also force it to do so by using  [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) that way output will get sent and your php script would be running even after ajax is completed

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);  //update
ob_end_flush();  //update
echo json_encode('status'=>'200');
ob_end_flush(); //flush PHP buffers
ob_flush();
flush();  // flush OS buffers
```

On some browsers you might notice that the loading [symbol](https://www.red-gate.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Chrome-Loading-Circle.jpg) would keep spinning even when the browser had received all the response that's because the HTTP connection between server and browser is still open. So if you want to avoid that you also need to close the connection manually , add this after `flush()`

```
header("Content-Type", "appliation/json"); //update
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
```

Comment: Got error  ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush and Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\testing\terminal.php:5)

Comment: Quick check what does `ini_get('output_buffering');` gives you? for _headers already sent_ you may try putting `header()` stuff at the very beginning of terminal php just after php opening tag

Comment: It response 4096

Comment: Strange.. try adding the code in update. Also you need to change `dataType:'html'` in javascript to  `dataType:'json'` because you are echoing json but telling jquery to expect html which is wrong

Comment: updated my post, when I'm out thing the header() to the begin of terminal it will directly end the process and not return any result. Seem to be the header('Connection:close') will even end the buffering.

Comment: Hmm... ok remove all the headers just try the upper `flush()` part

Comment: I solved the problem by using other method. Updated my code, this method only work properly on linux environment.